# CSS - hide the scrollbar on the x-axis when using keyframes animation

Tags: html, css, keyframe

I am trying to zoom into my background image. I am made a div for that matter and set it to `z-index -1`. , it needs to have `position:absolute` in order for other sections and animations to work properly on the page. 
The only thing that is happening now is that when the image is being zoomed in it creates a horizontal scrollbar at the bottom. How can I get rid of that, I have tried with overflow: hidden and overflow-x: hidden and setting it to diplay: block and display: inline-block as I saw that it was suggested here on SO, but it didn't work.

This is the css for that div:

```
#bg {
  background-image: url('/img/cover.png');
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: -1;
  animation: zoom 10s;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  animation: zoom 10s;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  0% { transform:scale(1,1); }
  100% { transform:scale(1.1,1.1);}
}
```

And html:

```
<div id="app">
    <div id="bg">
    </div>

      <div id="main-section">
      </div>

    </div>

    <div id="drawer">

      <div id="magazine-detail">
      </div>

      <div id="magazine-detail-carousel">
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="large-10 large-centered columns content">
    </div>

  </div>
```

**Update**

I removed horizontal scrollbar completely by setting:

```
html, body {
  ...
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Second try :)
You can avoid scrollbars (and using `overflow*: hidden`) by dimensioning your animated element considering its final size (I mean considering its size when it will be tallest and widest, which is at the end of the animation here)

Pen: http://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/RGOzar

If it may be +50% wide and twice taller, then width is defined at two thirds and height at half of viewport. 66% * 1.5 = 100% and 50% * 2 = 100%, no scrollbars :)

```css
#bg {
  background-image: url('/img/cover.png');
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: -1;
  height: calc(100vh / 2);
  width: calc(100vw / 1.5);
  animation: zoom 6s infinite;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: left top;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  0% { transform:scale(1, 1); }
  100% { transform:scale(1.5, 2);}
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <div id="bg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus, sit omnis modi facere architecto veritatis odio quod sed necessitatibus? Libero doloribus deleniti beatae in facilis animi, aspernatur blanditiis obcaecati illo.
    </div>

      <div id="main-section">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis harum saepe nam ratione, sint cum ea repellat ipsam quod sunt nisi officiis temporibus eveniet accusantium animi modi omnis! Eius, est!
      </div>

    </div>

    <div id="drawer">

      <div id="magazine-detail">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto iure aliquid incidunt modi culpa est iusto exercitationem, quaerat ab reiciendis nobis, unde corporis mollitia eius molestiae! Tempore sit vitae modi.
      </div>

      <div id="magazine-detail-carousel">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio consequuntur odit aliquam incidunt omnis ipsa tempore, error explicabo. Non, nam veritatis quae excepturi provident dolore doloremque tempore minus alias aliquid.
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="large-10 large-centered columns content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat, soluta rerum quasi libero pariatur tempora tenetur ipsam repellendus fuga, ea illo doloribus natus aliquam. Labore vero atque nostrum, consequuntur nobis.
    </div>

  </div>
```